# Roll back my github fork to an earlier commit

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo on github and I now want to roll my fork back to a known commit.  I can get the right files locally using

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

but then what?

How can I then commit that version back?  Do I `add` all the current files to the staging area and then `commit` and `push`?

EDIT:
Or is what I really need a branch?  Basically, the `HEAD` of the repo I originally forked uses some new dependencies that I can't rely on, so I want to take the code from that repo and shift it all back X days in the commit history.  I want the newly rolled-back code to be available on github so I can include it as a Gem in my Rails 3 app.

Is that better and can somebody show me how to do *that*?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to rewrite history and cause trouble for anyone who might have pulled the commit, just do a `git revert` and push that.

Comment: That's also interesting, thanks hammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to force a push after the reset:

```
git push origin +master
```

However, it is not a good idea to force push to a previous commit if the repository is public.

If you do not want to reset the local repository, but want the public one to go back a commit, use a refspec like `master~1:master`:

```
git push origin +master~1:master
```

A branch with commits that do not contain the dependencies can be used in your scenario. For example consider the branch's name to be `without_dependencies`:

```
git branch without_dependencies master~1
git push origin without_dependencies
```

Everyone will be able to see this new branch and work on it.

Comment: I have edited my answer with details on how to push a branch. If you are still confused, let me know.

Comment: I'm getting it now I think.  In your example would I need to create the `without_dependencies` branch myself before pushing, or does the command automatically create it?

Comment: The branch has to be created __manually__ before the push. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Great, thanks Alan.  Context-specific strategies like this I find very helpful when getting my head around git.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to (after your local reset) `git pull -s ours origin master` which will discard all changes from the merge, making the result your local HEAD, but leaving the history intact. You'd have a crappy commit sitting there, but you'd be able to then continue with `git push`, etc, how you normally would.